# Is there a way to detect a mobile Safari audio interruption — headphones unplugged — with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari, html5-audio, soundmanager2

I'm working on an HTML5 audio player built with jQuery and SoundManager.

So far, we've been unable to determine whether there's a way to detect an audio interruption event (unplugging headphones, for example) in mobile Safari. Right now, we're stuck with a player left in a 'playing' state even though the iOS has suspended any audio playing trough the player.

Comment: Are you saying that the audio playback stops but the player's UI is stuck in playback mode? Can you provide some sample source?

Comment: You're correct, Brian. Aside from dropping in the entire SoundManager code, etc... you can see a live version of the player [here](http://performancetoday.publicradio.org/listen/).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue now with a webpage using WebRTC. I found that if you have an `AudioContext` object, you can listen to its `statechange` event. On unplugging headphones, state of context becomes to `suspended`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/onstatechange

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried polling the property object.position (SM2 object) or object.currentTime (Audio object) or even the property object.paused? You could ensure that position/currentTime is incrementing every time it's polled - if not take action.

Comment: That's certainly an option, but it doesn't align with the lib in that we're responding to events occurring — events that are actually happening rather than events that are not.

Comment: If there isn't an event already and keeping your code entirely event driven is a big concern then you can always implement the polling within the SM2 library and trigger a new event which you handle in your code or create your own wrapper library and add the event that way.